# Adding multiple annotations and removing only one specific annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

In my project I'm adding multiple annotations, but I need to remove only one annotation.

Is there any way I can specify an annotation?

I have tried to use dynamic variable during the creation, but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Remember to check the meaning of tags and words you use. *Annotation* has different meanings in different contexts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be worked

```
   -(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    // Do other stuff
    annotationToRemove = view.annotation;    
  }
```

You can also implement the **didDeselectAnnotaionView** method as well.

for reference check this [Annotations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html)